# Case insensitive Contains in LINQ without making ToLower or ToUpper

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the customers which Company contains currentSearchViewValue.I want the LINQ to be case insensitive. I write the following:

```
string currentSearchViewValue = searchView.Query;
var currentCustomersSearched = customers.Where(x => x.Company.Contains(currentSearchViewValue, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

When I build it says that Contains has no overloads that take 2 arguments. I've seen a lot of examples on internet and they are very long or don't work. Is there a way to do what I want in one line?

Comment: What is `x.Company`?

Comment: Patrick Hofman a string

Comment: Try `x.Company.IndexOf(currentSearchViewValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0` if `x.Company` is a `string`

Comment: LINQ to Objects, Linq to SQL, Entity Framework?

Comment: Try using IndexOf as mentioned in Dmitry's comment. There's no overload of string.Contains() that's case insensitive

Comment: Stephen Kennedy LINQ to Objects I believe.

Comment: You can try: `x.Company.ToLower().Contains(currentSearchViewValue.ToLower())).ToList()`;